# Remove firsts n documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to periodicly remove firsts n stored document. How can I do it? I tried to get e.g. document no. 150000, to get it's timestmap and remove all documents with lower timestamp, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually achieve it using a single `_delete_by_query` request with corresponding `sort` and `size` parameters. Assuming that `timestamp` is the the name of your date field, `sample_index` is your index and `sample_type` - type name, the query looks like this:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/sample_index/sample_type/_delete_by_query?sort=timestamp&size=5

{"query":{"match_all":{}}}
```